# How to change style of a character based on a condition

Tags: reactjs

I want to give the color red to each 'e' letter in the text. I think I just need to wrap them in a span where the condition is met but couldn't figure it out. The below code is how far I came so far.

Here's the non-working code and the output is `h[object Object]llo`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const str = "hello";
  const myArr = str.split("");
  let output = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    if (myArr[i] === "e") {
      output += <span style={{color:'red'}}>myArr[i]</span>;
    } else {
      output += myArr[i];
    }
  }
  return output;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Yes, but you cannot do string concatenation on React elements. Either really generate HTML and use https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml, or create an array of React elements / string.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (myArr.map(elem => {
  return elem === 'e' ?
    <span style={{color: 'red'}}>{elem}</span> :
    <span>{elem}</span>;
}));
```

Comment: With this solution, each letter ends up being a value of an array. It seems to work for this example but failing to display properly for Arabic, an RTL language. I would like to have the whole text as one value with some spans in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you like an one liner

```
<span>{str.split('').map(x => x === 'e' ? <span style={{color:'red'}}>{e}</span> : e)}</span>
```